# Instance Variables and Bitfield

Tags: objective-c, instance, bit, bit-fields, ivar

I was trying to do an instance field of 1 bit in Objective-C, however when I try this `@property BYTE Z : 1;` I get an error saying `Property name cannot be a bitfield`.

What Can't I do so? Is there a workaround this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest allocable unit of memory is 1 Byte of most machines.There isn't a way to allocate 1 bit, it may be not mappable.It must contain all ASCII characters.
So just use a Byte and then read the bitmask.

Use something like:

```
@property (nonatomic) Byte byte;
```

Then use a macro for reading:

```
#define BitAtIndex(byte,index) (byte & (1<<index))!=0
```

PS: Of course the index can't be greater than 7.

Comment: I was checking what are available data types in Objective-C, I though why not use BOOL for 1 bit ints, is ti a good idea?

Comment: Yes, you could use it.A BOOL commonly used 1 Byte of memory too, but I  don't think that you need to save memory so much.You could also avoiding to read the bitmask.That unless you have a lot of BOOL and fear to run out of memory.